# Suggestions to concise this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-development-server

When the request.params.name field comes in via the request, i want the .name value of the object to get rendered with the pic: piece so we can render the web page with the proper picture.

Ive tried slicing to get persons.bros.whateverthenameis but the json object cannot be read properly when it gets passed to express' render method. So instead of passing willis_pic, Llama_pic, Carter_pic (which are merely just persons.burns.whateverthenameis) etc id like to pass in persons.burns.(req.params.name) but it will not work properly because the req.params.name is a string and is not recognized as the dot notation that I would like it to be. To be clear, I would like to pass persons.burns.Willis or persons.burns.Llama etc into the pic:param of the render method in a more concise way because all of these if statements are crap. Ive used json parse and stringify as well, neither will work and output undefined when i attempt to log them to the console.

router.get("/profile/:name", mid.requiresLogin, function(req,res,next) {

```
    var persons = {
        bros: {
            Willis: src = 'https://www.coloradocollege.edu/academics/dept/filmandnewmedia/images/Students/2018-19/Major%20Photo%20Border_WillisZetter_2019.jpg',
            Llama: src = 'https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQFQwEfmSpR1bQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0?e=1568851200&v=beta&t=lX01L9YxKGJmgkGT0FwQdN1o2-oNyxA18c42q_IPcfU',
            Carter: src = 'https://cctigers.com/images/2019/2/8/Richardson2019.jpg',
            Quang: src='https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5103AQE3RFIlv9FMEw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?e=1568851200&v=beta&t=yL9fgzubo7_XZpgmbFVRwDYUYULiGVPAf091qzq5Rm8',
            Maslow: src='https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQHHMv2-Fo0ppg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?e=1568851200&v=beta&t=5KYt7vrP-iXkgy0s2eDtLvDgnge0IF2DoSELDOnm4Gg',
                Beem: src='https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQG1_8PHv_WGoQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?e=1568851200&v=beta&t=NnVjW5UjQeXG8e0QwhsKe4XvFcU8JUbgHd7d5TRSww8'

        }
    };
    //if the obj.name is === (Any of the names that are pic variables) render that persons prof
    User.findOne({name: req.params.name}, function (err, obj) {
        if (req.params.name === "Willis"){
            var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros.Willis));
            var willis_pic = JSON.parse(pic);
            return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: willis_pic}) <--- want to get rid of this so we can insert the req.params.name variable but it won't work properly when trying to access the json obj.
        }
        else if(req.params.name === "Llama"){

            var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros.Llama));
            var llama_pic = JSON.parse(pic);d
            return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: llama_pic})
        }
        else if (req.params.name === "Carter"){
            var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros.Carter));
            var carter_pic = JSON.parse(pic);
            return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: carter_pic})

        }
        else if (req.params.name === "Quang"){
            var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros.Quang));
            var quang_pic = JSON.parse(pic);
            return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: quang_pic})
        }
        else if (req.params.name === "Maslow"){
            var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros.Maslow));
            var maslow_pic = JSON.parse(pic);
            return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: maslow_pic})
        }
        else if (req.params.name === "Beem"){
            var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros.Beem));
            var beem_pic = JSON.parse(pic);
            return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: beem_pic})
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look up the `req.params.name` property on the `bros` object, and if the property exists, render it. Remember not to ignore errors either - the `err` is often the first parameter to prompt you to check it first:

```
const name = req.params.name;
User.findOne({ name }, function (err, obj) {
  if (err) {
    // make sure to handle errors, don't just ignore them
    // res.render... "there was an error"
    return;
  }
  const pic = persons.bros[name];
  if (!pic) {
    // handle case where the name is not in the object, if this is a possibility
    return;
  }
  return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name, from: obj.burns, pic });
});
```

Comment: This works and looks great man but i am confused. You set const pic = persons.bros[name]....Why is name in an array and not just persons.bros.name like it was originally declared? Also, you simply say persons.bros[name], there is not dot notation before [name]? How does js know how to dot notation down the object if theres no dot?

Comment: That's bracket notation, not an array. Eg if `obj = { foo: 'x' }` and you have a variable with `foo` in it, `const key = 'foo'`, then you can use bracket notation to look up the key on the object: `const val = obj[key]` and then `val === 'x'`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help my friend, I really appreciate it. Happy Coding

Comment: Ok i lied one more question for you for my sanity. Could this have been done using dot notation? If so pls give your solution. Have been coding for like 3 years and I've only used dot so it makes sense why i wasted so much time on this

Comment: No, it wouldn't be possible with only dot notation, because to write the code concisely, you want to look up a property whose property name is stored in a variable, which can't be done with dot notation.

Comment: Got it. We can use dot for easy access to json objects and object when things get a bit more tricky like my example here. Again, thanks so much for your help I can happily say that I learned something valuable today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 User.findOne({name: req.params.name}, function (err, obj) {
    if ["Willis","Llama","Carter","Quang","Maslow","Beem"].includes(req.params.name){
        var pic = (JSON.stringify(persons.bros[req.params.name]));
        var tmp_pic = JSON.parse(pic);
        return res.render('profile', {title: 'Sign Up', name: req.params.name, from: obj.burns, pic: tmp_pic})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man this works.... Can you please elaborate to me on what is going on with the: 
"["Willis","Llama","Carter","Quang","Maslow","Beem"].includes(req.params.name)" line? You create an array of the names and then if the req.params.name is in the array we continue? Also, you say persons.bros[req.params.name] in the next line. There is no dot after bros? and why is req.params.name in bracket as it was an array?

Comment: The first line you mentioned checks to see if the variable `req.params.name` is contained in the array of names.


The second line you mention accesses the property `req.params.name` in the object `persons.bros`


This being said I attempted to mimic the exact functionality that you showed in the question. CertainPerformance's answer would be a better approach.